# fetching array from sql and checking with conditions

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop

I need help...I'm trying to retrieve data from sql table and compare it with if statement for certain IDs and updating a variable accordinly. But it seems that the variable is not updating for some reason. Below is my code..

```
$query2 = "SELECT prcID, tProDone 
          FROM vw_fdwTracker
          WHERE AgrNo = '$agreement'";  

$result2= sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2);
    if ($result2==false){
        die( "<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   

$current = 0;       
while($id= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){       

    //echo $id['prcID']." ". $id['tProDone'].'<br>';

    if(($id['prcID']===3) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=12.5;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===4) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=25;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===5) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=37.5;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===9) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=50;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===10) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=62.5;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===14) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=75;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===12) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=87.5;
    }elseif(($id['prcID']===17) && ($id['tProDone']===TRUE)){
        $current=100;
    }else{
        $current=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$current` is not updating? If you mean `$current`, then if you have multiple rows, it will overwrite itself on every loop.

Comment: Also, if they all require `$id['tProDone']` to be true, why not just do a wrapper for that `if($id['tProDone'] === true) { }` then inside that, do a switch? It would probably be a little cleaner. That way you don't need all the `&& ($id['tProDone']===TRUE`'s.

Comment: yes $current is not updating..I have multiple rows with different IDs, and I want check for certain IDs and update $current accordingly...so even if it overwrites itself it should have some value in end but here i'm not getting any output...in the end $current is still 0....

Comment: Are you sure you need the `===` instead of just `==`?

Comment: both === and == are not getting me any results...although i don't need === i just put it there to check if it gives any output..

Comment: Oh wait your code doesn't fall inside the loop. Is that what is supposed to happen? You have a bracket before the `if` so that closes the loop -> `}if`

Comment: oh sorry that was by mistake, its just typo...but code still doesn't work..

Comment: But `echo $id['prcID']` produces values?

Comment: yes it produces value...it displays all the IDs ..if i put it in while loop along with $id['tProDone'], it show all the IDs and their status as true or false.

Comment: Try `if(!$id['tProDone']) die();` Then you'll know if that value is good working. Then do `if($id['tProDone']) { switch($id['prcID']) { case(3): die();}}` Inside the `case()` do a number you know is valid, see if it dies.

Comment: @Rasclatt..i tried your solution but still cant update the variable $current, other than that everything is working fine...on each condition I can echo out different text messages but can't update the variable...i've no clue why...:(

Comment: Did you assign to an array and `print_r()` like I suggested in my answer to see if any conditions are being met?

Comment: echo $id['prcID']." ". $id['tProDone'].'<br>'; with this I can print out the array..it show ID no and its current status..ex.1 1,
2 1,
3 1,
4 0,
5 0,
6 0,
7 0,
8 0,
9 0, I still have to try your second solution...going to try it now...

Comment: But did you try my example to see if the array recorded the assigned digits anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving to an array so you know if it's working or not:

```
function getCurrentArr($agreement,$conn)
    {
        $query = "SELECT prcID, tProDone FROM vw_fdwTracker WHERE AgrNo = '$agreement'";
        $result  =  sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die( "<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        return $result;
    }

function getCurrVal($value)
    {
        $return[3]    =    12.5;
        $return[4]    =    25;
        $return[5]    =    37.5;
        $return[9]    =    50;
        $return[10]   =    62.5;
        $return[14]   =    75;
        $return[12]   =    87.5;
        $return[17]   =    100;
        return (isset($return[$value]))? $return[$value] : 0;
    }

$curr    =  array();
$result  =  getCurrentArr($agreement,$conn);
while($id= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(!$id['tProDone']) {
        $curr[]    =    0;
        continue;
    }

    $curr[]    =    getCurrVal($id['prcID']);
}
// See what this gets you for an array
// If what is in this array is what you expect, then
// make the $curr array the variable, but you will overwrite
// every time it loops, just keep that in mind
print_r($curr);
```

Comment: i tried this solution and here is the output from it...Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 12.5 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 )

Comment: That's why, only the value for the 4th key in the array had valid conditions (true and matched an id)

Comment: Plus when setting one variable in a loop, the last row value, in this case 0, is applied to the variable.

Comment: but any value should be applied to variable only if the condition is matching but here its somehow changing it to zero without having condition matched....i have other data where 4 conditions are matching...now my problem is i'm using this variable value to update a progress bar through css... it being an array is giving errors...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define $current variable value at starting of code  just do your code like below it will also work on loop

```
$id['prcID']=3;
$id['tProDone']=false;   

if(($id['prcID']==3) && ($id['tProDone']==true)){
   $current=12.5;
}else{
   $current=0;
}
echo $current;
```

Comment: thax ram singh for the suggestion. i know it is now needed but its always better to declare variables in advance...any ways its still now working...